# How do I change the logic to jQuery UI dialog?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

Here is the original code (It's not actually real code, hope you guys can get my point):

```
function whichButton(a,b){
    if(confirm('I dont wanna compare them?')){
        return "yes";
    }
    else{
        return "no";
    }
}
```

And what I need to do is to change this logic to jQuery UI which can replace the `confirm` in navigator.

What I want is to follow the same logic as above (`myConfirm()` is a function I sealed it with jQuery UI dialog).

```
function whichButton(){
    myConfirm('I dont wanna compare them?',function(yes){
        if(yes){
            return "yes";
        }
        else{
            return "no";
        }
    });
}
```

I just want the original logic to work when using jQuery UI dialog.

Comment: You can't make a direct switch to a jQuery UI dialog, as it isn't a truly modal dialog from a code execution point of view - the code that displays it needs to return before the browser will actually display the dialog and accept user input. It may be easier to help you if you can tell us what you want to do with the result once you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to compare two variables,If you click 'yes' on the confirm dialog the function returns 'yes' alse you will get the compare result.

```
function maxNumber(a,b){
   myConfirm('I dont wanna compare them?',function(yes){
    if(yes){
        return "yes";
    }
    else{
     return a>b?a:b;
    }
  });   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.My sample's sucks.The point is not compare two numbers.The point is when you press the button,I can get the return value.like the confirm() in native navigator.like var var whichbutton=maxNumber(1,2);

Comment: I edit my question just now,hope this sample can express what I want to ask clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following example:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation

```
$( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );

$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height:140,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            doCompare(a, b);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
});

function doCompare(a, b) {
    return a>b?a:b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.the old question has a little mistake.I edit my question just now,hope this sample can express what I want to ask clearly.